# page shows all the records for the first time before pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, salesforce

**Problem Description:**

We have a ROR application which is making a call to the external system and displaying the results on the page. But when it displays the results for the first time it shows all the rows returned from the external system,for ex 2000 records, and then it refreshes by itself to show the first 10 records.

here is the code:

**Controller:**

```
  def index
    @filter_options = {
      "My Accounts" => "my",
      "My Team's Accounts" => "team"
    }

    @selected_filter = params[:selectedfilter] || "my"

    @accounts = Account.index as: current_portal_user, filter: @selected_filter
  end
```

**Model class**:

```
  def self.index options = {}
    user = options[:as]
    role = user.role
    contact_id = user.contact_id
    account_id = user.account_id

    query_string = if options[:filter].nil?
      Account.get_all_accounts(account_id, contact_id, role)
    elsif options[:filter] == "team"
      Account.get_myteams_accounts(account_id, contact_id, role)
    elsif options[:filter] == "my"
      Account.get_my_accounts(account_id, contact_id, role)
    elsif options[:filter] == "id"
      self.index_basic_query + "WHERE Id = '#{options[:id]}'"
    end

        more_results.uniq { |acc| acc.Id }
   end
```

Can some body please tell me why the page is showing all the records of the query for a fraction of second and then refreshes by itself to show the first ten records.

**Note:** I am completely new to Ruby and ROR and trying my best to fix this problem. The code I posted above is pseudo code so please bear with me if there is any syntax error or as such.

**EDIT:**

**GOAL:**
When the results for the query are shown on the page, first it shows all the records from the resultset before doing the pagination.
For ex: I open the page and select the filter and click on 'go' button and for the filter I selected I am expecting 2000 records. So what is happening is page shows all the 2000 records and then within fraction of a second, it refreshes and then shows the first 10 records of the total 2000 resultset.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you write that code yourself or inherit from whomever created the project?

Comment: Also I'm a bit confused here are you querying a database or a web API that takes SQL like [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql)?

Comment: The sql query is sent to salesforce via databasedotcom ruby gem and here is the link for the query method in the above code: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/heroku/databasedotcom/master/Databasedotcom%2FSobject%2FSobject.query

Comment: Do you think you could edit your question to include the actual code you are working on? Or at least provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also often helps if you can describe your actual goal in simple terms and not just the problem.

Comment: "In our application we get account information from salesforce with databasedotcom, which
is displayed to the user in a paginated table..." Provide as much actual information (within reasonable bounds) as possible.

Comment: @maxcal I am really sorry for your time, I posted the real code and then the goal as you mentioned. Once I again i am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem :). Its much more clear now.